# Moment Formatting in minutes for over 60 minutes

Tags: react-native, format, momentjs

I am working on an app that tracks a users activity over time. When the user completes the activity I'd like to show the total time in minutes. Currently when the user passes 60 mins it resets the minute counter.

If a user is active for 1hr:2min I'd like it to show as 62 minutes. Is this possible? Currently it rolls over to 2 mins. This is what I have and it works great for under 60 minutes. I appreciate the feedback.

```
export const formatWalkTimeInMinutes = (walkSeconds) => {
  return moment().hour(0).minute(0).second(walkSeconds).format('m');
};
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
return moment.duration(walkSeconds, "seconds").asMinutes()
```

Comment: Thank you @PieterBuys! This worked though I wrapped it in Math.Floor to take away the decimal places. Appreciate the feedback greatly.